# How to convert in python a list to an array with keeping the same dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, list, keras

I am using Python 2.7, tensorflow 1.14 and keras 2.2.5. The method model.fit accepts only array as parameters. I have one of the parameter as a list. When I convert the list to an array using np.array, I get an error saying that the parameter must be of shape 5 but I gave an array of shape 1.

How can i convert the list to an array and keep its dimension?

Comment: that is very strange, normally `myArray = np.array(myList)` should work

Comment: could you give us a [minimal reproducible example]? so that we can see what is going wrong?


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am building my model using keras and the method model.fit. All the parameters have to be arrays. First, I got this error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'" . It was about this variable: "training_txt [[53, 56, 53, 58],...[52, 53, 53, 58, 6]]". So, I used np.array: training_txt= np.array (training_txt ). When I print the result it shows me the variable: "training_txt [list([53, 56, 53, 58]) ...list([52, 53, 53, 58, 61])]". But, I get the error "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected the_labels to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)"